# JQuery quiz: count the number of repeat value from group of answers?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, radio-button

I have a form with a series of questions, radio buttons.  Each group is
the same 5 values, order scrambled so user doesn't see pattern.

When the user clicks a button, I want to first get the value of each
group (which I think I know how to do with
`$('input:radio[name=bar]:checked').val();`) and then see how many total
of each string was picked.

As in this sample question:

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="loner">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="partier"
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="clueless">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="romantic">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="pragmatic">
```

So, I have maybe 10-20 questions with answers, which are mapped to these (made up here) values. At the end, the user clicks a button and will need to total up the number of times each of the 5 terms was chosen, see which was chosen the most, as in "you are a romantic".

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Slightly different way to go about it: http://jsfiddle.net/pbysh/u8FQX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mM7X4/

```
var values = ['loner','partier','clueless','romantic','pragmatic'];
var result = [];

$.each( values, function( i, value){
  result.push({
    value: value,
    sum: $('input:radio[value='+value+']:checked').length;
  });
});

result.sort( function( a,b){
  if( a.sum < a.sum ) return +1;
  if( a.sum > a.sum ) return -1;
  return 0;
});

alert('You are a '+result[0].value );
```

Comment: `function (a, b) { return a.sum - b.sum }` would suffice, I guess. )

Comment: @biziclop Thanks, but for some reason fails when I try it, wonder what I messed up see [http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/ndCsa/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/ndCsa/3/) **fixed**

**EDIT**: I found what I messed up. Thanks.

Comment: ok, in the meanwhile add a `<label>` around each radiobutton + its label :)

Comment: You didn't change the event binding to your button:    `$(document).on('click','#calcbtn',function(){` Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/ndCsa/4/